# PHP / JS - Firefox Cookies Expires not set

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, cookies

This is the way how I set cookies in JavaScript:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {

    expires = "expires=2147483647";

    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/"+";" +";samesite=None" + ";secure=true";
}
```

This is the way how I set cookies in PHP:

```
function setMyCookie($name, $value) {
    $t = 2147483647;

    setcookie($name, $value, [
        'expires' => $t,
        'path' => '/',
        'samesite' => 'None',
        'secure' =>  true     
    ]);
    
}
```

**Works on Chrome**: Expires / Max age is set correctly.

**Does NOT Works on Firefox**: Expires / Max age is set NOT correctly. When I close the browser (=session is done), the cookies are deleted.

How can I set cookies also in Firefox properly?

Thanks,
BlueMatrix

Comment: Are you using private window in firefox? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1318854

Comment: @Kaushik, thank you for your help. No, it was not the private modus. But you brought me to another idea, that it does not need to be the JS or PHP which causes the issue, it's just the browser itself. I de-installed and installed my Firefox, now it works. Many Thanks!